# Why does the universal selector show two elements when a border is applied in an empty html file? (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm doing the Web Fundamentals course at Code Academy and noticed something strange.

If I have an html file like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
```

and a CSS file like so:

```
* {
  border: 2px dashed black;
}
```

I will see two elements outlined. Something that seems like the very edge of my browser window, and then a slightly smaller box inside it. What are those two boxes? There are no elements in my HTML file so what is being outlined?

At first I thought it was an outline for the `<html>` and `<body>` elements, so I tried removing `<body>`, tried removing `<head>`, and eventually even removed `<html>` but still there are two boxes.

Thanks!

Edit: I did try searching, as recommended, but could not find a previous answer. It was quite hard to find an answer to this specific question, thanks.

Comment: Browser's probably still rendering HTML and Body elements as they're required.

Comment: Your Web browser is probably implicitly creating those elements in memory.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you take out the `HTML` and `Body` tags, they will still be rendered on the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The start and end **tags** for the `html` and `body` elements are optional.

You deleted the tags, but not the elements. You can see this by looking at the document in a DOM inspector (such as you can find in most browser developer tools).

(The same applies to `head`, but it is `display: none` by default).

[image: screen shot of developer tools]

Comment: Interestingly, you can delete the `<head>` and `<body>` elements from the developer tools, but you can't delete the `<html>` element. In Chrome, at least.

Comment: If you delete `<head>` and `<body>` in Chrome's dev tools do the two boxes still show up as outlined?

Comment: So that's weird, when I try this experiment and delete the `<head>` tag from chrome dev tools, the CSS disappears too. Deleting just the `<body>` tag does delete one box, leaving just a box attributed to `<html>`. Though in Chrome the boxes are very long (`<html>` is length of browser window, `<body>` just a bit shorter) and very thin (only 4px wide). In CodeAcademy they are as wide as the browser window.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers will automatically put `<html>` around your document, `<head>` around your head elements, and `<body>` around your body elements. These are required HTML elements and cannot be absent.

Therefore, even an "empty" page has a visible `<html>` and `<body>` elements for your border to be applied to.